# I would like to know about backup policy in any RTOS

Tags: operating-system, backup, rtos, freertos

I am studying RTOS and its backup policy.

Is there any RTOS which has backup policy like save data from SRAM to non-volatile memory before power failure?

It does not have to be an RTOS. any OS is ok :)

Does anybody have an documentation about it?

Best, 
Mirae

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the responsibility of the RTOS but something which needs to be designed in to the system if required, whether or not using a RTOS. Issues can occur if a power failure occurs during writing to the non-volatile memory. There are numerous methods of managing this, such as having the non-volatile memory mirrored and checked with a CRC, so that if there is a power failure only one copy is corrupted.